# Finding most recent date of max purchase from two tables

Tags: mysql, date, select, join, max

I have two tables. First lists `userid`, `amount` - of the item purhased and the `date` - in which it was purchased. The second has `userid`, and the `date` as well as their current `address`. Each time a user changes his/her address a new row is inserted inside `t2`.

How do I find the most recent address of the user with the largest purchase made?

```
t1:
userid amount date

t2:
userid date address
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.userid, t2.address 
   from t1 
   join 
      t2 on t2.userid=t1.userid  
   where amount = (select max(amount) from t1) 
   order by t2.`date` desc 
   limit 1
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a28d6/1)

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!